# DiscordJS Invert Image Command Showing Nothing

Tags: discord.js, node-canvas

I have code for inverting an image. Since there was no tutorial on it, I tried to follow pieces of tutorials to put together the command.

I logged the image and it is showing fine. When I run the command, there are nor errors, but the image does not show.

```
module.exports = {
  name: "invert",
  description: "Invert your avatar image",
  async execute(message, member) {
    const Canvas = require("canvas");
    const Discord = require("discord.js");

    let theCanvas = Canvas.createCanvas(218, 218);

    const ctx = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
    const theAvatar = await Canvas.loadImage(message.member.user.displayAvatarURL);
    console.log(theAvatar);
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, theAvatar.width, theAvatar.height);

    for (var i = 0; imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
      imageData.data[i] = 255 - imageData.data[i];
      imageData.data[i + 1] = 255 - imageData.data[i + 1];
      imageData.data[i + 2] = 255 - imageData.data[i + 2];
      imageData.data[i + 3] = 255;
    }

    console.log(imageData);

    const attachment = new Discord.Attachment(imageData.toBuffer());
    message.channel.send(attachment);
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I display the image is much more simple.

```
client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("?" + "avatar")) {
    message.reply(message.author.displayAvatarURL());
  }
});
```

I think the problem might be when you said `const theAvatar = await Canvas.loadImage(message.member.user.displayAvatarURL);`